# List the content of a directory mssparkutils

Tags: python, mssparkutils

I used the following code to list the files in a directory but it is showing the entire path instead of just the file name:

```
historical_logs_adls_path = (
    f"abfss://{staging_container_name}@{staging_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/"
    f"{staging_dirname}"
 )


mssparkutils.fs.ls("/")
mssparkutils.fs.ls(historical_logs_adls_path)
```

I simply need the list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use basename function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-basename-method/

Try the below:

```
import os

historical_logs_adls_path = (
    f"abfss://{staging_container_name}@{staging_account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net/"
    f"{staging_dirname}"
 )

file_list = [os.path.basename(file.path) for file in mssparkutils.fs.ls(historical_logs_adls_path)]
print(file_list)
```